# Is a BLE advertisement required to provide a non-empty local name?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gap

I am porting some code from MacOS to Windows. MacOS always returns a non-empty local name in advertisement packets while Windows seems to always return an empty local name in an advertisement packet.

Comment: That is wrong. Windows returns an advertsing device's name if the name frame (0x08 - LE_GAP_AD_TYPE_LOCAL_NAME_SHORT or 0x09 - LE_GAP_AD_TYPE_LOCAL_NAME_COMPLETE) is advertising. However that is not required. Device may advertise its name or may not. For GATT enabled devices there are other ways to get device's name so it may not include the name frame into its advertisement packets.

Comment: So I am wondering if the MacOS is cooking the advertisements because the MacOS seems to always return the local name with the advertising data.

Comment: I have no idea how BLE works on MacOS. But I know how it works on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

No, having a local name is not a requirement as part of sending out adverts. The requirements for BLE adverts depend on the type of advert, but for the simplest and most common advert type (ADV_IND, a.k.a scannable & connectable advert) the only requirement is the device's public or random address. None of the advert types require the local name to be part of the address. You can read more about this in the Bluetooth Specification v5.2, Vol 6, Part B, Section 2.3.1 (Advertising PDUs) [[1]](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification/).

You can also do a scan with nRF Connect on an Android/iOS device and you'll see that many devices don't have the name as part of advert, instead you get N/A as the device's name:-

[image]

Comment: How can i set that name so, My application can't show as N/A. I am using c#

Comment: @DarshitGandhi I read you can set the name (sorry can't remember exactly) in the attributes or profile. The other app will need to have code that will look for that attribute and display it.