# what does bluetooth transmit when it is just visible

Tags: bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I want to know what does bluetooth transmit when it is just visible, not connected. I googled , I saw it transmit name of the device and mac address but just them ? Can we add some extra datas or can we change them dynamically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For classic Bluetooth (i.e. pre Android API level 21), you are restricted with the data that you can send in the inquiry response (which is connection-less data sent over the air). There are three types of inquiry response data that can be sent over the air:-

**Inquiry Result**:-

[image]

**Inquiry Result with RSSI**:-

[image]

**Extended Inquiry Result**:-

[image]

In other words, depending on what the scanning device asks for, the result can be different, and even though in all cases it is not just name and mac address, you cannot add just random extra data to the inquiry response.

---

For Bluetooth Low Energy (i.e. Android API level 21 and later), advertising data can be dynamic and can be configurable. The minimum advert report can only contain the device's Bluetooth Address (either the public or the random address). In other words, even the name of the device is not a requirement. However, it is usually common to include both the address and the name as this gives more information about the advertising device.

You can read more about this in the [Bluetooth Specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification/) v5.2, Vol 6, Part B, Section 2.3.1 (Advertising PDUs). Also have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [Is a BLE advertisement required to provide a non-empty local name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67491002/is-a-ble-advertisement-required-to-provide-a-non-empty-local-name)
- [How BLE works: advertisements](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-low-energy-advertisements-part-1/)
- [BLE advertising primer](https://www.argenox.com/library/bluetooth-low-energy/ble-advertising-primer/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did some research and I saw bluetooth low enegry is usable for andorid api level 21 and above. Is there any alternative for api level 14 ? I will use this technology to share some informations between 10, 20 maybe 100 devices. But this devices will not be paired, just recieve a small value and that is it, close the bluetooth. Maybe you have another idea to do it ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include classic Bluetooth part as well

Comment: Thanks for your so detailed comment. Can we send some data by  changing these values ? Like changing Class_Of_Device with our datas ? Or is there other way ?

Comment: You can theoretically change the class of device to send some data, but unfortunately this breaks the Bluetooth specification which is why I don't recommend it. My personal recommendation is to us Bluetooth Low Energy if you can. Sending data over adverts is one of the many advantages BLE has over classic Bluetooth. BLE has been in use since 2012 so most devices support it now.